# Find previous searches in less command

Tags: bash, terminal, less-unix

In vim, if I am in search mode by pressing `/`, I can press `Ctrl`+`p` to find my last searched string, and press that combination again to find an even earlier searched string, and so on. I can do the same on commandline in emacs mode.

I want to do the same with `less` command (i.e., press `/`, and then press `Ctrl`+`p` to find what I searched for previously, and then press `Enter` to search that term again. Can I do that? How can I do that?

Edit: reworded to make the question clearer.

Comment: @JamesBrown I think the OP wants to navigate  within a file backwards via a search string rather than view a list of previously entered search strings. `?` is the key to search backwards in less

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To browse `less` search history (`~/.lesshst` by default, `man less` and `LESSHISTFILE` for more):

1. `less` a file, for example `less ~/.lesshst`
2. type <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>?</kbd> to search forward or backward or <kbd>&</kbd> to show only matching lines (<kbd>/</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> or <kbd>&</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> for non-matching)
3. use up and down arrows <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to browse the history, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to choose one
4. <kbd>n</kbd> repeats the search, <kbd>N</kbd> in reverse direction. To reset the screen after showing only the matching lines with <kbd>&</kbd>, type <kbd>&</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This is totally what I'm looking for.  If I could, I'd select yours as the accepted answer

Comment: Why they decided `N` instead of `p` (stands for "previous")? Confused.

Answer (score 2):

Use `/` to search forward. 
Use `?` to search backward.

Use `n` for the next occurrence of the search item and `N` for prior occurrence.  This works for both forward and backward searches.

And as pointed out in the comments if less history is enabled you can carry your search item across invocations of less.

`man less` and `man lesskey` for the details.